# Error Code: 1054. Unknown column '' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

```
delete ana.* from table1 as ana
where 
ana.qname=(select ID from tab1 where LOCAL_NAME='xxxxx')
and exists(select 'x' from table2 an 
where
ana.node_id=an.id and 
an.QNAME_ID IN (select ID from tab1 where LOCAL_NAME in('bbb')));
```

why above query is not working in mysql.same query is working in oracle.

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'ana.qname' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*A priori*, your query looks ok.  I would start by formatting it and qualifying *all* column names:

```
delete ana
    from table1 ana
    where ana.qname = (select t1.ID
                       from tab1 t1
                       where t1.LOCAL_NAME = 'xxxxx'
                      ) and
          exists (select 1
                  from table2 an
                  where ana.node_id = an.id and
                        an.QNAME_ID IN (select t1.ID
                                        from tab1 t1
                                        where t1.LOCAL_NAME in ('bbb')
                                       )
                 );
```

I think the error is pretty clear:  `table1.qname` doesn't exist.  I will also add that comparing something called "name" to something called "id" looks suspicious.  I suspect you are simply using the wrong column name there.  Perhaps the intention is `qname_id`.